# BigQuery: decimal represented by 2 integers - how to encoded?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I use dataflow to import data from MongoDB to BigQuery.

In Mongo there is a decimal variable `Value.Amount`. in the example = -4.

After loading to BigQuery, this value is stored as a dict of two values: high and low
in my example:

`"Amount":{"high":-5746593124524752896,"low":4}`,".

Is there a good way to get value "-4" in BigQuery? I'm trying with different format functions in BQ, but so far I haven't found a good solution.

I'm trying with different format functions, but so far I haven't found a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you’re trying to import data from a Mongo collection to a BigQuery table using Google Dataflow and are facing issues with the Decimal128 type, which is not supported by BigQuery.

I managed to circumvent this issue by researching in forums and also looking at how the conversion is done in the bson library of Python. Based on this, I created a temporary function in BigQuery that takes the ‘high’ and ‘low’ values and returns the real value.

Here is the function I created:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION decimal128(highString STRING, lowString STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js
AS r"""
  const _SIGN = BigInt("0x8000000000000000");

  const high = BigInt(highString);
  const low = BigInt(lowString);
  const sign = (high & _SIGN) !== 0n ? 1 : 0;
  const exponent = Number((high & BigInt("0x7FFF800000000000")) >> BigInt('49')) - 6176;
  const digits = Array.from(low.toString()).map(Number);
  const value = [sign, digits, exponent];
  const _sign = value[0];

  var digitsArray = [];
  value[1].forEach(digit => {
      if (Number.isInteger(digit) && digit >= 0 && digit <= 9) {
          if (digitsArray.length || digit !== 0) {
              digitsArray.push(digit);
          }
      } else {
          throw new Error("The second value in the tuple must be composed of integers in the range 0 through 9.");
      }
  });
  const _int = digitsArray.length ? digitsArray.join('') : '0';
  const _exp = value[2];
  const signStr = ['', '-'][_sign];
  const leftDigits = _exp + _int.length;
  let intPart, fracPart, dotPlace;
  if (_exp <= 0 && leftDigits > -6){
    dotPlace = leftDigits
  }
  else{
    dotPlace = 1
  }
  if (dotPlace <= 0) {
      intPart = '0';
      fracPart = '.' + '0'.repeat(-dotPlace) + _int;
  } else if (dotPlace >= _int.length) {
      intPart = _int + '0'.repeat(dotPlace - _int.length);
      fracPart = '';
  } else {
      intPart = _int.substring(0, dotPlace);
      fracPart = '.' + _int.substring(dotPlace);
  }
  const exp = '';
  return signStr + intPart + fracPart + exp;
"""
```

I hope this helps solve your problem. If you have any more questions, please let me know.

Regards,
Jacy